# Get Current logged In User Id in Lightning Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, user

I referred this to get logged in user Id in the flow but it doesn't seem to be working for me - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A86vHSAR

I have the below flow that I created to debug a bigger problem. And I was able to narrow down to 1 thing that is causing problems in my project.  -> the formula field used to fetch the current user doesn't work and returns an empty value in Mobile App. Which is resulting in no record fetched using the Get Record element. This only happens in Mobile and when I debug in the browser I can see the User Id is populated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Actual Screen:

[image]

In the last screen, the current User is coming as empty. Is this the right approach to fetch logged-in user IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Field Service Mobile App Flows but is not listed in the help doc of FS limitation. I have asked Salesforce to update the doc.